# How do async in window phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

- In app.xaml.cs

  ```
   private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      A.onEndApp();
    }
  ```
- In class A

  ```
  async public static void onEndApp()
    {
    string temp=await doSomething();
    //code here
   }
  ```

I have a problem,when I close an app,and then `onEndApp()` method is run,
when `doSomething()` run complete and `{//code here}` is not run,but if I put `A.onEndApp()` in 
another method it run normaly,for example  `Application_Launching()` method,it will be run
`{//code here}`

I think when app is running it no problem,but when app is closing it run await complete and then stop,I want to run complete method when I close app in async.

Comment: return Task from onEndApp instead of void. Then .Wait it, you _have_ to block if you want something to run when it closes, better yet - don't do it.

Comment: Could u tell more detail ?

Comment: Why fo you want to run it async? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1):

After Application_Closing is executed (synchronously), the OS will terminate the process. There *might* be a short delay before it does so, and that *might* be enough for you to finish writing to isolated storage, or it might not in which case you'll end up having corrupted state

I'll just take a direct quote from "[Beware the perils of async/await in application lifecycle event handlers (in fact in *any* event handlers)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/07/31/beware-the-perils-of-async-await-in-application-lifecycle-event-handlers-in-fact-in-any-event-handlers.aspx)" on Andy Wigley's blog.

> #### Calling async code from Application_Deactivated or Application_Closing
>
> The guidance here is “don’t'”. If you write your apps carefully, you can be saving changes to persistent data as you go along, so you shouldn’t have anything to do in the application lifecycle events.
>
> If you must, you can try doing something like this:
>
> SomeAsyncMethod().AsTask().Wait()
>
> If the operation completes within the timeout period AND it doesn’t deadlock due to needing 
>   to pump the UI thread, it will work… but don’t count on it.

Comment: Why is the guideline don't? What's the problem with closing it synchronously :) This answer looks like a start of a good one but I feel there is much room to expand about the problem of making a blocking call when the app is closing, and it's worth to emphasize the fact there is no guarantee it'll even finish.

Comment: Great, much better :) Nice answer btw.

Comment: Im using AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func) to synchronize an awaitable. It work great in Application_Closing. Here's the source for the helper: https://github.com/mikaeldui/Partisk.NET/blob/master/Partisk.API/Helpers/AsyncHelper.cs

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var task = A.onEndApp();
    task.Wait();
}

async public static Task onEndApp()
{
    string temp = await doSomething();
    //code here
}
```

Otherwise, you're effectively just spinning off a thread that will never get a chance to run to completion, because the application is closing out from underneath it, and the thread will get terminated before it can run.

Comment: Code is correct but explanation is wrong. The reason you need to wait is because otherwise the `async` code will return before it is done executing (there's no other thread).

Comment: I believe this will cause a deadlock, because `onEndApp` will try to resume on the UI thread after the `await`, but that thread is being blocked by the `Wait()`. You will need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. (Or the possibly simpler and dirtier solution: `Task.Run()`).

Comment: @StephenCleary - Would it be more accurate to say that there's not *necessarily* another thread? It would be fairly common (though not required) for the `doSomething()` to spin up another thread, either directly, or under the hood.

Comment: @svick - I tested the code above, with a simple `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));`, and no deadlock. What sort of scenarios are you thinking might result in a deadlock?

Comment: @KenSmith: I explain the [deadlock issue on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: I doubt there's threads in this case; the only reason to use a thread for async work is to keep the UI responsive during CPU-bound operations, but in this case the app is exiting so there's no point in doing that - you'd just execute the CPU-bound operations synchronously instead. So, I assume that there is *not* a thread in the op's scenario, and blocking on the async work (which does raise the possibility of deadlocks) is a necessary hack to prevent the app from exiting while the work is in progress.

Comment: @StephenCleary I don't think so and it bit me in the past before several times. I recommend using `Dispatcher` btw.